# Changing directory within Chef Recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, rhel7

This is my first attempt at writing a chef cookbook. I'm attempting to write a recipe that will automatically install git, make a new directory (`git_repo/`), change to that directory, initialize to be a git repository, and then connect to the remote git repository once I run chef-client on my node. I got it to install git and make the directory but I am unsure how to write within the recipe to change directory to git_repo. the code I have is

```rb
package 'git' do
  action :install 
end 

directory '/home/git_repo' do   
  mode 0755   
  owner 'root'   
  group 'root'   
  action :create 
end

execute 'change' do
  command "sudo cd git_repo" 
end
```

Is there a better resource type to use besides execute for this particular action? If so, could someone elaborate on it?

Comment: FYI there's no need to use `sudo`. Everything that `chef-client` does is done with superuser privileges, unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#properties) resource as a property `cwd`:

> `cwd`: The current working directory from which a command is run.

In order to run a command from within the `git_repo/` directory as working dir, use the following declaration:

```rb
execute 'init' do
  command "git init"
  cwd "/home/git_repo"
end
```

As this would very likely fail on the second chef run (because `git init` will not succeed), you should [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) this resource using the `creates` property:

> `creates`: Prevent a command from creating a file when that file already exists.

```rb
execute 'init' do
  command "git init"
  cwd "/home/git_repo"
  creates "/home/git_repo/.git"
end
```

As a general note, I am not sure, if you really want to initialize an empty repository. If you just want to clone a repository, use the [`git`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) resource.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll take what you said into consideration.